# ascii characters 128 to 158

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, sybase, sap-ase

All these ascii characters from 128 to 158 are not getting saved in database properly.
These characters were inserted into database throu jboss(java service) application from UI into sybase database.
These characters were saved as '?' in database.
Java is using utf code set. and database is using iso_1

Comment: This is hardly a question... the only question mark I see is the symbol that was stored in your database.

Comment: ASCII is a 7bit character set, so there are no values above 128 (decimal) - What characters are causing you problems, and what code are you using for connecting to the database, etc?

Comment: That special character was saved as '?' in database

Comment: shaw - The characters like em-dash, Euro symbol etc.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII does not have the € character, so any conversion from Unicode text to ASCII *should* convert it to something like ?. Converting to [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) would share the same problem, so you probably want to consider changing the collation on the database to a suitable one for the character set you need to include.